# How to avoid ODBC driver installation for a Node.js application?

Tags: sql-server, node.js, odbc

I'm using https://www.npmjs.org/package/odbc in an application targeting Windows.

Therefore it requires users to install Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434), which is a problem if the user doesn't have admin rights.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another system for databases, mongoDB, sqlite, etc. if your application is simply, i recommend sqlite

Comment: I have no control over the database sadly. My application just fetches the data it needs from it.

Comment: If you have no call option, the only thing I can think of is to use create a server machine that has installed the ODBC driver, and the other machine have a client vercion in regard to requests is more work but if you want to install the driver in each and every one of the client machines, is the only solution I can think of, good luck man.